# How to trigger a click on another app from Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I want to open an app which contains buttons that I want to trigger a click. The app will then open a browser page when done, which I want to close. I want to automate the whole thing. I know to invoke the app and send system event for key press using AppleScript. But how to do that using Swift. I can open the app, but how to make the button click? Is Swift the wrong tool for UI automation?
I am intending to run the swift program as a script `#!/usr/bin/swift`.

Comment: Yes, Swift is the wrong tool for UI automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to say it isnt doable with swift on osx - and that is more because of osx than swift.

anyway. there are no public 'native' straight-forward APIs for it and while it might be doable with the accessibility API that'd be a major pain.

I'd recommend you go with AppleScript (Sure, your swift 'app' could trigger a lot of AppleScript to do all the heavy lifting (like you said) but then .. kinda useless to start out with swift anyay, eh? ;)))